# Modifying src attr using replace

Tags: javascript, replace, src, attr

Hello i made a code where i get the last part of the src data and replace _t for empty space like this.

```
 // Get the current image number
        var current = $(next.index("img"));

        var nextUrl = next.attr("src").replace("_t", "");
```

This is the img example

```
<img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/28/66523124_b468cf4978_t.jpg" />
```

so in the example case i get this URL

```
http://farm1.static.flickr.com/28/66523124_b468cf4978
```

My question is ... I have to modify that code to actually change that at the beginin of the URL

in the Script im working now the thums are

```
<img id="extra_15" src="data/16/t_15_images.jpg" border="0" width="70px" class="">
```

And the big images are

```
<img id="extra_15" src="data/16/15_images.jpg" border="0" width="70px" class="">
```

how do i change that?

Comment: beginning, middle, end, doesn't really matter as long as there is only one occurence of `_t` in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Switch around the pattern you are looking for. Instead of `_t` do `t_`.

`var nextUrl = next.attr("src").replace("t_", "");`

Comment: Damn jajaja im so tired, yep just realized how stupid is my question